# Call says cannot read property 'then of undefined (looks valid )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, es6-promise, chaining

I don't know if it is React.JS , or just me forgetting something with promises but I'm getting this error

```
const promise = SAIIndexedDB(response.data)
promise.then(function(result){
    this.setState({
         loadingMedications: false                    
    });  
})
.catch(function(error){
    console.log('error', error);
});
```

Error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

line number shows it is this line  `promise.then(function(result){`

I was reading through this and it seems correct...
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

Reason I want/need a promise is that loadingMedications gets set to false which closes the spinner when the data is done loading from the function call SAIIndexedDB(..)

Here is the function that is calls

```
export function SAIIndexedDB(customerData){
    var status = "start in helpers";
    const dbName = "SAIOffline";
    var request = indexedDB.open(dbName, 2);
    request.onerror = function(event) {
    };

    request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
        var db = event.target.result;
        var objectStore = db.createObjectStore("medications", { keyPath: "value"});
        objectStore.createIndex("short_description", "short_description", { unique: false });
        //objectStore.createIndex("email", "email", { unique: true });
        objectStore.transaction.oncomplete = function(event) {
            // Store values in the newly created objectStore.
            var customerObjectStore = db.transaction("medications", "readwrite").objectStore("medications");
            customerData.forEach(function(customer) {
              customerObjectStore.add(customer);
            });
            status = "done"
            return status;
        };

    };

}
```

Comment: Does the function `SAIIndexedDB` return a promise? If you can provide some implementation details of that function, it might be easier to solve this question.

Comment: ok, I will show the code for that , I suppose it is not a promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update your code like the followings:

```
SAIIndexedDB(response.data).then(function(result){
    this.setState({
         loadingMedications: false                    
    });  
})
.catch(function(error){
    console.log('error', error);
});
```

```
export function SAIIndexedDB(customerData){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var status = "start in helpers";
    const dbName = "SAIOffline";
    var request = indexedDB.open(dbName, 2);
    request.onerror = function(event) {
           reject(event)
    };

    request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
        var db = event.target.result;
        var objectStore = db.createObjectStore("medications", { keyPath: "value"});
        objectStore.createIndex("short_description", "short_description", { unique: false });
        //objectStore.createIndex("email", "email", { unique: true });
        objectStore.transaction.oncomplete = function(event) {
            // Store values in the newly created objectStore.
            var customerObjectStore = db.transaction("medications", "readwrite").objectStore("medications");
            customerData.forEach(function(customer) {
              customerObjectStore.add(customer);
            });
            status = "done"
            resolve(status);
        };

    };
}

}
```

Comment: Interesting.  I am getting an error though .   `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined`      which would be on the caller,  -  this is odd because that setState is done properly , it is setup exactly how React is supposed to be.  it is already set to true to display the spinner, so it just needs to be set to false to make the loading spinner disappear.

Comment: fixed it,  i posted a question ,  problem with `this`      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58830907/setstate-in-nested-promises-in-react-app-is-throwing-error-cannot-read-property/58831092#58831092