# React app is throwing error Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined in nested promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Getting this error in my React application inside nested promise calls

> Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Strange to me is outside of the promise setting value to both true and false without a problem.

```
console.log('about to set false')
this.setState({
    loadingMedications: false                    
}); 
console.log('about to set true')
this.setState({
    loadingMedications: true                    
}); 


SAIIndexedDB(response.data).then(function(result){
    this.setState({
         loadingMedications: false                    
    });  
})
.catch(function(error){
    console.log('error', error);
});
```

So above the console writes out fine and no error
but then in the promise , the catch throws the error  -  It takes about a minute for this promise to return as it is loading 170k records into an offline indexeddb database and then returns and thus that loadingMedications is a loading spinner that needs to be set to false in order to hide it.

Thoughts on why ?

Comment: Hi Miller, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The issue is with `this`.**

Instead of this,

```
SAIIndexedDB(response.data).then(function(result){
    this.setState({
         loadingMedications: false                    
    });  
})
```

you need to use arrow function which auto binds `this`,

```
SAIIndexedDB(response.data).then((result) => {
    this.setState({
         loadingMedications: false                    
    });  
})
```

Comment: About to try it,  but if a problem with `this`  how does getting rid of `function` work ?  please explain.

Comment: wow, ok that works.    1. i want to stick with the arrow function, but out of pure curiously , how can it be binding to `this` without arrow function?   also i'm lost on why this is a problem,  any article i can read on the specifics?

Comment: Here is the good information about binding [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/bind-javascripts-this-keyword-react/) without arrow function.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is assigning `this` to a variable and use that variable in callback

```
const self = this;
SAIIndexedDB(response.data).then(function(result){
    // replace $this with $self
    self.setState({
         loadingMedications: false                    
    });  
})
.catch(function(error){
    console.log('error', error);
});
```

Comment: ok,  i'm lost of why this is a problem.   I remember version 1 of Angular  (angularjs)  i was always doing  var vm = this;   .... so then angular 2 + it was typescript and i don't recall ...      Any articles ?   thx